# Sklearn LinearRegression: Indexing causes change in regression score

Tags: python, indexing, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I stumbled over some weird behaviour of LinearRegression from scikitlearn. The code fits the features contained in `NP.M` (the feature matrix) to the data `NP.flatDW` which has `NP.flatweights` as weights. The feature Matrix has the following shape:

```
>>> np.shape(NP.M)
(2121, 27)
```

Therefore, `NP.M[:, np.arange(0, 27)] == NP.M` but despite this is true

```
>>> np.sum(NP.M[:, np.arange(0, 27)] == NP.M) == np.size(NP.M)
True
```

the following occurs:

```
>>> reg = LinearRegression()
>>> reg.fit(NP.M[:, np.arange(0, 27)], NP.flatDW, sample_weight = NP.flatweights)
>>> reg.score(NP.M[:, np.arange(0, 27)], NP.flatDW, sample_weight = NP.flatweights)
0.99461571849945363
>>> reg2 = LinearRegression()
>>> reg2.fit(NP.M, NP.flatDW, sample_weight = NP.flatweights)
>>> reg2.score(NP.M, NP.flatDW, sample_weight = NP.flatweights)
0.99473478592046516
```

As you can see, the score for `NP.M[:, np.arange(0, 27)]` is lower than the score for `NP.M`, but they are supposed to be equal.

It does not seem to be an error in the score function, because

```
>>> reg.score(NP.M, NP.flatDW, sample_weight = NP.flatweights)
0.99461571849945363
```

yields the same as `reg.score` above and predictions from both regressions differ.

So, how does indexing change the feature matrix in the background? Are there some hidden numerical issues?

Comment: Check the dtype of the original array, and the dtype of the indexed one.

Comment: @Shiva Both yield dtype('float64')

Comment: Interesting. When you index, it creates a new copy of the original array. Due to the representation of doubles in memory, perhaps there is some loss in precision when the copy is done.

Comment: This is strange. Technically, each time you train a model with the same data, you will get different similar scores because it is based on probabilities. Have you tried looping through the same training instance with the same data and then showing the set of scores ?

Comment: Agree with @Coldspeed. To add, maybe its some sort of tolerance level which is reached. Try checking it multiple times with some inbuilt datasets for both cases and see if a pattern emerges. If not satisfied, you can put this issue on scikit-learn issue page. Also on the default boston dataset provided with the scikit, changes are still present but the difference is 10^(-15).

Comment: Edit: When using `fit(X[:, np.arange(0, 27)].copy())` I am able to reproduce the exact result. But without the `copy()` the above mentioned change happens.

Comment: @Fnayou Repeated fitting of the same training instance did not change the score in this case.